# $_POST inside for loop returning null

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop through the `$_POST['job-destination[$i]']`, however its returning null when I did `$i = 0; var_dump($_POST['job-destination[$i]']);`

**PHP code**

```
// Experience loop
$experience = '';

for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++){
   $experience .="<h4>Experience $i: </h4>
   <b>Destination</b>: ".$_POST['job-destination[$i]']."<br/>";
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Destination</p>
      <div class="radio-btn-grp">
        <input class="job-destination" name="job-destination[0]" value="Australia" type="radio" required="">
        <label for="job-destination">Australia</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio-btn-grp">
        <input class="job-destination" name="job-destination[0]" value="Canada" type="radio">
        <label for="job-destination">Canada</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
  <p>Destination</p>
  <div class="radio-btn-grp">
    <input class="job-destination" name="job-destination[1]" value="Australia" type="radio" required="">
    <label for="job-destination">Australia</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-btn-grp">
    <input class="job-destination" name="job-destination[1]" value="Canada" type="radio">
    <label for="job-destination">Canada</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: change $_POST['job-destination[$i]'] to $_POST['job-destination'][$i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP**

Replace this :

```
$_POST['job-destination[$i]']
```

with this :

```
$_POST['job-destination'][$i]
```

In your HTML inputs, using `[]` like so will automatically indexing your input :

**HTML**

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <p>Destination</p>
  <div class="radio-btn-grp">
    <input class="job-destination" name="job-destination[]" value="Australia" type="radio" required="">
    <label for="job-destination">Australia</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-btn-grp">
    <input class="job-destination" name="job-destination[]" value="Canada" type="radio">
    <label for="job-destination">Canada</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

you should also change your for loop to iterate your `$_POST['job-destination']`

**PHP**

```
for ($i=0; $i <= count($_POST['job-destination']); $i++){
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you dont need to set a value in the `name="job-destination[0]"` if you do `name="job-destination[]"` it is all you need to do. Let the browser do the work for you

Comment: Amend your answer and Ill give an UV

Comment: @RiggsFolly Actually I have multiple radio button sets wherein the html code mentioned above repeats multiple times. Would it work in that case?

Comment: Yes all you need to do is give each RadioButtonSet a unique name, so `name="job-destination[]"` then `name="job-source[]"` then `name="job-applicant[]"` and so on